# wxpython make StaticText limit

Tags: wxpython

I have an issue with `StaticText`, and I do not know how to make it accept only the following `data = '0123456789.'` . Of course, when you type any letter, the letter is automatically deleted. Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean TextCtrl, don't you? You can use a validator, there is an example in the wxPython demo, which is a part of the Docs and Demo package.

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed it although it is different from what I want to achieve, for example I need to enter decimals, but not in a group, something like this -> "12.4"